# FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

When i try to create a new project in pycharm and choose my base inerpreter as C:\Anaconda3\python.exe this error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 170, in main
    do_pyvenv(path, system_site_packages)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 88, in do_pyvenv
    venv.create(path, system_site_packages=system_site_packages)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 363, in create
    builder.create(env_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 66, in create
    self.setup_python(context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 204, in setup_python
    copier(context.executable, path)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 192, in symlink_or_copy
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall python and make sure you checked "Set environment variables" checkbox